# Expand a jsonb array proprietie

Tags: arrays, postgresql, expand, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

By selecting from a jsonb field in a pg3 database, i'm getting results like this one:

> res
>   text
>
> ["card", "dog", "chair"]
>
> ["house", ]

The query:

```
select DISTINCT (table.properties->'attr'->>'objects') as arrays from table
```

How can I expand that array so each element appear in one row?

Comment: Check out: `jsonb_array_elements_text()` : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html

Comment: That function demands a jsonb as input, what I have is a "text" field. I've tried it already, but couldn't make it work...

Comment: Why are you using `->>`? That returns `TEXT`. You should be using `->` to return a `JSONB` object.

Comment: That was it. I've been staring at it way to long, thanks so much!!